# Editing django database on same page without moving to other view function

Tags: javascript, django

I have a details page that displays the details of the parts and has option for adding stock of that part and list of stock that has already been added

```
def part_details(request,pk):
    temp =check_session_exist(request)
    if temp != True:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(temp)

    my_list=populate_nav_bar() //displaying navigation bar
    temp_list = models.part_list.objects.get(part_id=pk) // get stock information

    if request.method  == 'POST': //adding stock of the current part
        form_entered=forms.part_stock_form(request.POST)
        if form_entered.is_valid():
            temp = models.part_stock()
            temp.part_id = models.part_list.objects.get(pk=pk)
            temp.entry_date = form_entered.cleaned_data['entry_date']
            temp.supplier = form_entered.cleaned_data['supplier']
            temp.amount = form_entered.cleaned_data['amount']
            temp.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('parts:part_details',args=[pk]))
        else:
            print("invalid field")
            return render(request, 'part_details.html',
                      {'part_temp': temp, 'my_list': my_list, 'part_stock_form': form_entered})

    return render(request,'part_details.html', {'part_temp':temp_list,'my_list':my_list,'part_stock_form': forms.part_stock_form})
```

[image: view of my page]
now I want o to edit the stock from the same page where do I put the function for this. can't I just call the function for it without redirecting it to other view and redirecting back to the same view. does javascript provide a function for adding/editing database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to edit the db whithout reload the page? If this is the case, you can use ajax for that, or in the form put the same url and it will return to the same view